# Question about symbols on this forum

Tags: discussion, mathjax

So I found out it uses "latex"

can I just write down the uhh formulas for the symbols I want, and it shows up after I hit the post your question button?

Comment: One big difference is that you need to enclose your LaTeX in $'s

Comment: Our most upvoted question on meta might be helpful to you.

Comment: Editing help: [LaTeX](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex)

Comment: You do not have to wait until you hit the post your question button for it to show up. Scroll down a bit to preview your current content. That is precisely what your post will look like if you hit that button. If it does not look right you probably have some syntax issues.